# Styled Components with React - form onSubmit not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

So I wanted to make a Styled Components form component and then use it in a bigger react component. Problem is, when I wanted to attach an onSubmit, it didn't really work. My Styled Components form component:

```
const FormWrapper = styled.form`
    margin: 2vw 0 0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
`;
```

My react parent component:

```
const Form = () => {

  const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted');
  };

  return(
      <FormWrapper>
          <Input name="username" placeholder="username"/>
          <ErrorMssg >This username doesn't exist!</ErrorMssg>
          <Submit value="register"/>
      </FormWrapper>
)};
```

I tried something like this:

```
<FormWrapper onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

And even something like this in my Styled Components component:

```
const FormWrapper = styled.form.attrs({
  onSubmit:props=>props.onSubmit}`
})`
  margin: 2vw 0 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
`;
```

For now I made it work with this:

```
const FormWrapper = styled.div`
  form{
    margin: 2vw 0 0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
  }
`;

const Form = () => {

  const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted');
  };

  return(
      <FormWrapper>
         <form autoComplete="off">
           <Input name="username" placeholder="username" autoComplete="off"/>
           <ErrorMssg >This username doesn't exist!</ErrorMssg>
           <Password name="password" placeholder="password" autoComplete="off"/>
           <ErrorMssg>The password is wrong!</ErrorMssg>
           <Submit value="log in"/>
         </form>
    </FormWrapper>
)};
```

Comment: You also need  to add `type=submit`

Comment: Adding `type=submit` to the `<Submit value="log in"/>` with onSubmit on the Styled Components form component made it work! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<Submit value="log in" onClick={handleSubmit}/>
```

Comment: It works fine now, thank you so much! I was so sure that if you wanted to catch both submit button click and pressing 'enter' on an input you had to attach an event listener to the form, but your solution does the exact same thing and actually WORKS!